# Null propagation operator and extension methods

Tags: c#, roslyn, c#-6.0

I've been looking at Visual Studio 14 CTP along with C# 6.0 and playing with the null-propagation operator.

However, I couldn't find why the following code does not compile. The features are not yet documented so I'm not sure whether this is a bug or extension methods simply are not supported with the `?.` operator and the error message is misleading.

```
class C
{
    public object Get()
    {
        return null;
    }
}

class CC
{
}

static class CCExtensions
{
    public static object Get(this CC c)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        C c = null;
        var cr = c?.Get();   //this compiles (Get is instance method)

        CC cc = null;
        var ccr = cc?.Get(); //this doesn't compile

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Error message is:

> 'ConsoleApplication1.CC' does not contain a definition for 'Get' and no extension method 'Get' accepting a first argument of type 'ConsoleApplication1.CC' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: If you remove the null-propagation operator, does the code compile? If not, it could be a problem with the compiler finding the extension method, not the operator.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I don't work on the Roslyn team, but I am fairly confident that this is a bug. I took a look at the source code and I can explain what's happening.

First off, I disagree with SLaks answer that this isn't supported because extension methods do not dereference their `this` parameter. It is an unfounded claim, considering that there's no mention of it in any of [the](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/540281) [design](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/540514) [discussions](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/543875). Plus, the semantics of the operator turn into somethat that roughly looks like the ternary operator (`(obj == null) ? null : obj.Member`), so there's not really a good reason why it couldn't be supported in a technical sense. I mean, when it boils down to generated code, there really is no difference in the implicit `this` on an instance method and the explicit `this` on the static extension method.

The error message is a good clue that this is a bug, because it's complaining that the method doesn't exist, when it actually does. You may have tested this by removing the conditional operator from the call, using the member access operator instead, and having the code compile successfully. If this were an illegal use of the operator, you would get a message similar to this: `error CS0023: Operator '.' cannot be applied to operand of type '<type>'`.

The bug is that when the `Binder` is trying to bind the syntax to the compiled symbols, it uses a method `private static NameSyntax GetNameSyntax(CSharpSyntaxNode, out string)` [[link]](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Binder/Binder_Expressions.cs#4f1cdd072cd03edb) which is failing to return the method name that is needed when it tries to bind the invocation expression (our method call).

A possible fix is to add an extra `case` statement to the switch in `GetNameSyntax`[[link]](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Binder/Binder_Expressions.cs#4f1cdd072cd03edb) as follows (File: [Compilers/CSharp/Source/Binder/Binder_Expressions.cs:2748](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Binder/Binder_Expressions.cs#a1cec4b775b3aded)):

```
// ...
case SyntaxKind.MemberBindingExpression:
     return ((MemberBindingExpressionSyntax)syntax).Name;
// ...
```

This was probably overlooked because the syntax for calling extension methods as members, that is using the member access operator) winds up using a different set of syntax than when used with the member access operator vs. the conditional access operator, specifically, the `?.` operator uses a `MemberBindingExpressionSyntax` that wasn't taken into account for that `GetNameSyntax` method.

Interestingly, the method name is not populated for the first `var cr = c?.Get();` which compiles. It works, however, because local method group members are first found for the type and are passed to the call of `BindInvocationExpression` [[link](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Binder/Binder_Expressions.cs#4f16bb9e7b5eb292)]. When the method [is being resolved](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Binder/Binder_Expressions.cs#e629f8eb1cc0f167) (note the call to `ResolveDefaultMethodGroup` [[link](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Binder/Binder_Expressions.cs.html#c1b721af8f430543)] before trying to `BindExtensionMethod` [[link](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Binder/Binder_Expressions.cs.html#077b987f26fc69b5)]), it first checks those methods and finds it.  In the case of the extension method, it tries to find an extension method that matches the method name that was passed into the method, which in this case was an empty string instead of `Get`, and causes the erroneous error to be displayed.

With my local version of Roslyn with my bug fix, I get a compiled assembly whose code looks like (regenerated using dotPeek):

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        C c1 = (C) null;
        object obj1 = c1 != null ? c1.Get() : (object) null;
        CC c2 = (CC) null;
        object obj2 = c2 != null ? CCExtensions.Get(c2) : (object) null;
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 31):

Yes. This is a bug. Thanks for bringing this up.
The sample is supposed to compile and should result in a conditional invocation of Get regardless if Get is an extension or not.

Usage of "?." in cc?.Get() is an indication that caller wants cc null-checked before proceeding further. Even if Get could handle null somehow, caller does not want that to happen.

Comment: I completely agree that this is a bug. I should mention that this is "the official" answer, because @VSadov is the person who implemented this feature in Roslyn.

Comment: This has been fixed in the change http://roslyn.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/345430ed2dfce55bdfe71dc8754cace33ad242be

Answer (score 4):

The point of the null-propagation operator is to avoid derefencing a `null` value.

However, extension methods do not deference their `this` parameter, and in fact can be called perfectly fine on `null` values.
(although the method itself is likely to throw an exception if it doesn't expect `null`)

Therefore, it would be unclear whether a null-safe extension method call would skip the call or not.

Comment: It appears, based on the error message (assuming the behavior doesn't change) that the `?.` operator is only syntactically valid for instance methods, not extension methods.  That actually seems like a sensible solution to the problem.

Comment: @Servy: Yes; this is probably why they disallowed it.

Comment: Ok if this is the point then don't you think that the error message should be different than "extension method not found"?

Comment: @nosalan - Extension methods are called using the class.  You are trying to call one using an instance variable.  Calling an extension method using an instance variable makes no sense to me, whether the null propagation operator is present or not.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: Wrong.  The whole point of an extension method is to call it using the instance.

Comment: @Slaks - Duh!  I was thinking calling a regular static method.  Brain Freeze!

Comment: This is just WRONG. Designing extension-methods to handle `this`-parameter to be null - is a code smell! Most of BCLs extension methods (and any other I know) are throwing `ArgumentNullException`, like they are used to. Extension method should 'looks like' and behave just like instance method.