# ASP.NET MVC Model in View (ViewModel) ternary operator null check

Tags: c#, .net, view, ternary-operator

I know that the ternary operator ("?") can be used checking if the value is null and if it's not null proceeding to the "chained methods let's call it". Example: `Model?.FirstOrDefault();` Why doesn't this work? I want to say "if the Model is not empty call the FirstOrDefault method, else don't do anything". Getting this error

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'
>
> System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(...) returned null.

Comment: That's called a null-conditional operator; it isn't ternary.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24148313/34397

Comment: @SLaks I think you meant [Null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators).

Comment: @LewsTherin ok I read the docs anyway it should work, shouldn't it? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Is it possible that `Model` is *not* null but also contains no elements?

Comment: @KirkLarkin It's null

Comment: Are you sure? [This code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/b95HJp) proves that `?.` works with `FirstOrDefault`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this because `FirstOrDefault()` is an [Extension Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

> Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise modifying the original type. Extension methods are a special kind of static method, **but they are called as if they were instance methods** on the extended type.

The fix would be to just not use the [Null Conditional Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) which is just syntactic sugar.

```
string myVariable;

if (Model != null)
    myVariable = Model.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically I have used the ? for setting accessors for an API data extract as the ? means that that value can be null. I think this is more of what you are looking to do:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TableName.AttributeName))
 {
   FirstOrDefault();
 }
```

Comment: `?` at the end of a value type declaration (like `int?`) is a [Nullable type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/) and is not the same as a [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) (`?.`).

Comment: you are right. I guess I misunderstood his intention with the '?'